# What is the difference in following declaration types in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, declaration, sqlplus

1: name varchar2(30):='uu' || '&(emp name)'; 

2: name varchar2(30):='uu' || '&emp name';

I am not getting whats the difference () is making.

In 1st case name = uu&(emo name and 
In 2nd case it promts user to enter value.
Please can any body explain me the concept behind this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL*Plus interprets names beginning with `&` or `&&` and consisting of letters and digits (like a normal identifier). Such names are [variable usages](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aPlus_FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_.26_and_.26.26.3F); unless already defined, these get replaced with user input.

Note that the `(` after `&` in your first line is not an alphanumeric character, so SQ*Plus does not detect a variable reference.

Add `set define off` at the top to disable this.